# Windows Batch: Pipe output from exe into a SET VARIABLE where output has spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file

There are a lot of Stack Overflow articles related to this, but no straight answers.

This command will output a bunch of words

```
OutputVariable.exe %FILEPATH%
```

Outputs:

```
Mary had a little lamb
```

In a batch file, here's how to get the output into a variable

```
for /f %%i in ('OutputVariable.exe %FILEPATH%') do SET SENTENCE=%%i
ECHO %SENTENCE%
```

Outputs:

```
Mary
```

Typically, the `FOR` command breaks at spaces.  Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('OutputVariable.exe %FILEPATH%') do SET "SENTENCE=%%i"
ECHO %SENTENCE%
```

`; , = <space> <tab>` are the standard delimiters in batch and in `for /f` result is automatically splitted by them. To deactivate delimiters you need `"delims="` in `for /f` options.

Comment: I'll add, he could echo every value by looping through them:

for /f %%i in ('OutputVariable.exe %FILEPATH%') do echo %%i

Comment: @NathanRice - not exactly.In `FOR /F` every token should be set in the options with `tokens=1,2,..` otherwise it will be inaccessible.Wile in plain `FOR` it's possible to iterate over every element.

Comment: `"delims="` was it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('OutputVariable.exe %FILEPATH%') do SET SENTENCE=%%i
ECHO %SENTENCE%
```